# Relationships don't work

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have 2 models: User and Rank

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password','registered_at','last_action','ip','about_user','reputation','rank','moderator_notes','verified','verify_code',
    ];
    public $timestamps=false;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public function ranks() {
        return $this->hasOne(Rank::class,'id','rank');
    }
}
```

And

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Rank extends Model
{
    protected $table = "ranks";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

'rank' column in user table should be same as 'id' in ranks table. Now I want to get both user and his rank info. Tried in many ways, because found many ways in internet. One of them was like:

```
$user = User::where('id',$id)->where('username',$username)->first()->ranks();
```

But now I cant access any user info, get just ranks info... My view looks like this:

```
Username: {{$user->username}}<br/>
Email: {{$user->id==Auth::id()?$user->email:'nerodomas'}}<br/>
Rank: {{print_r(Auth::user()->ranks()->name)}}
```

username and email should be from users table, and rank (name) - from ranks table... However I only get errors. Cal anyone help me? :) thanks!

P.S. sorry for question title, couldn't create anything better..

Comment: Just to clarify, can multiple users have the same rank?

Comment: @RossWilson Yes. Rank should be like Administrator, User, Moderator :)

Comment: or then I should use one to many or something like this?

Comment: Can users have multiple ranks or will they only ever have one rank? Also, just so I know is it possible at this point to change `rank` to `rank_id` in your users table?

Comment: users can have one rank, but many users can have same rank :D well it's possible

Comment: As long as it won't break anything I would suggest doing it as it will mean the naming convention for your models will be easier. If it will cause breaks then no worries.

Comment: Did either of the below answers solve your issue? If so, please will you mark one of them as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem in your relationship and DB schema. Your `ranks` table should have `user_id` column instead of `users` table having `rank` column.

If you follow above schema then your relation should be as:

User.php

```
public function ranks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Rank');
}
```

Rank.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**Update**

For `Many To Many` relationship your table should be as:

`user` table - |id|email|...

`rank` table - |id|name|

`rank_user` table - |id|user_id|rank_id|

The `rank_user` table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names.

Define relationship as:

User.php

```
public function ranks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Rank');
}
```

Rank.php

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Then you can query it as:

```
$user = User::where('id',$id)->where('username',$username)->with('ranks')->first();
```

And in your view you can use it as:

```
Username: {{$user->username}}<br/>
Email: {{$user->id==Auth::id()?$user->email:'nerodomas'}}<br/>
Rank: {{print_r(Auth::user()->ranks->first()->name)}}

Rank: {{print_r($user->ranks)}}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

**Update 2**

*To the response of comment below*

Make sure you have entry in DB something like this:

If your logged in user `id` is `1` then:

`user` table

```
|id|name|
+-------+
|1 |Sam |
```

`role` table

```
|id|name         |
+----------------+
|1 |Administrator|
|2 |Moderator    |
```

`role_user` table

```
|id|user_id|role_id|
+------------------+
|1 |1      |1      |
|2 |1      |2      |
```

Comment: echm.. Multiple users can have same rank, so I think this should be okay, no?

Comment: Then you should use many-to-many relationship. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks, but is the only problem here with relationship type? Is everything okay in controller, view, @Amit ?

Comment: I will update the answer soon, you can check it by yourself.

Comment: now getting `Trying to get property of non-object` in `Username: {{$user->username}}` this line

Comment: I am not sure why it's happening here as your `$user` variable seems to be a User Model object so this code `$user->username` must be running.

Comment: You may try like this in your controller `dd(User::where('id',$id)->where('username',$username)->with('ranks')->first()->username)`.

Comment: now problem is here `{{print_r(Auth::user()->ranks->first()->name)}}` , same `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Again you can debug it with `dd(Auth::user()->ranks->first())`. If it gives `null` then there must be no entry in `rank_user` table for this user.

Comment: yep, it gives null, what should i do then?

Comment: Make sure you have the entry in your `rank_user` table for this logged in user.

Comment: Then read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) it may help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your have your relationships the wrong way round.

If multiple users can have the same rank the that means a rank can have many users (hasMany).

Your relationships should be

**Rank Model**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'rank', 'id');
}
```

**User Model**

```
public function userRank()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Rank::class, 'rank', 'id');
}
```

Ideally, you would want to have the column on the users table called `rank_id`. This way you wouldn't have to define the local and foreign keys in the relationship and you would be able to call the relationship in the `User` model `rank()`.

With your user query `id` should be unique so you shouldn't need to query the username as well but I will use your original query as the example:

```
$user = User::where('id',$id)->where('username',$username)->first();
```

Then to get the rank relationship you can:

```
$rank = $user->userRank; //Rank model
$rank->name; //Rank name
```

Or even:

```
$rankName = $user->userRank->name;
```

Hope this helps!